# mongo schema not using default mongoose connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

Consider the following two files...

```
// orgSchema.js
var OrgSchema = new Schema({
   ...
});

exports.OrgDB = mongoose.model('Organization', OrgSchema);


// orgs.spec.js
var OrgDB = require('...').OrgDB;

describe('organizations', function() {
    before(function(done) {
        mongoose.Promise = Promise;
        mongoose.connect('...', done);
    });

    after(function(done) {
        mongoose.connection.close(function() {
            done();
        });
    });

    describe('simple test', function (done) {
        var org = new OrgDB();

        org.name = 'New Org';
        org.save(function(err) {
            if (err) done(err);

            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Notice, that I have two files.  If I place the schema in the *same* file as the mocha unit test, then everything works fine.  However, as it stands (with the schema being in a different file), the schema model (e.g. `mongoose.model`) doesn't recognize the default connection has already been made and therefore gives me the warning:

`Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html`

and the error:

`Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

Also, if I put the `mongoose.Promise and connect` lines in the schema file, everything works fine.

**How do I get the schema to use/recognize the default connection?**

Answer (score 1):

If it is a different file, what you need to do is to export the connection as you did with the schema. I would do something like:

```
const connection = mongoose.connect("mongourl")
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
module.exports = connection
```

And then I would require in the file you are using the connection.